# prototype and setTimeous

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

`setTimeout` doesn't work in the code below.

How can I fix it?

```
function Human(name, surname, sex) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.sex = sex;
};

Human.prototype.wash = function() {
    console.log(this.sex + ' ' + this.name + this.surname + ' ' + 'takes a cleaner and start washing')
}

Human.prototype.washing = function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(that.name + 'still washing...'), 3000
    });
};


function Human1(name, surname, sex) {
    Human.apply(this, arguments);
};


Human1.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
Human1.prototype.constructor = Human1;

Human1.prototype.wash = function() {
    Human.prototype.wash.apply(this);
    Human.prototype.washing.apply(this);
    console.log(this.name);
};

var Andrey = new Human1('Andrey', 'Balabukha', 'male');
Andrey.wash();
```

Comment: how is supposed to work? what do you expect to see here `console.log(this.name);`? and in your `setTimeout` you put `3000` in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout is in the wrong place. Should be:

```
Human.prototype.washing = function() {
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(that.name + 'still washing...');
    }, 3000);
};
```